# Conversion of this recursive formula to a general term of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursive-algorithms

I got puzzled trying to convert this particular recursive sequence to a general term of a sequence.

$$S_n=1+n+\sum_{j=2}^{n-1} j\times S_{n-j}\times\binom{n}{j}$$

Can somebody help me to reduce to the form of a sequence of $S_n$ that doesn't rely on previous terms?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The original problem is: Find how many endomaps are there for a set of n elements, that the composition of 2 same endomaps equals to the original endomap. This $S_n$ is the solution but I don't want it to be in recursive form.

Comment: Generating function is the obvious approach. Don't have time to work it out now so don't know if the best is regular or exponential.